# Exporting a specific user's content from Drupal 6

Tags: drupal, data-migration

I am new to Drupal. I am working with a preexisting website that has a couple dozen staff bloggers. Some of the bloggers need to have all of their posts migrated out to a database (the CMS they will be imported to is not yet known).

I have looked into a few modules for backups, but they don't seem to have the ability to choose what exactly is exported.

If anyone could give me some advice or direct me to an appropriate module, that would be fantastic!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views/) and [Views Data Export](http://drupal.org/project/views_data_export/) modules. 
However, you will need to learn a little about Views before making use of the Data Export module. You can follow some quick tutorials. You will not need any coding skills but concentrate on Views UI , Filters and Arguments.

Make a View on node as primary content, and add a filter (or an argument if you want to take the user ID from URL) for User: UID and add fields you want to get exposed as Fields. Then, in the style settings, choose "Data Export". Create a page display and give it a path.

You can also make the form advanced with exposed filters.